# How are holders in custom listView created?

Tags: android, android-listview

I saw a program for the custom listview in the following link
http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429&q=customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter

THIS IS THE CUSTOM ADAPTER:

```
public class WeatherAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Weather>{

    Context context; 
    int layoutResourceId;    
    Weather data[] = null;

    public WeatherAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Weather[] data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        WeatherHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new WeatherHolder();
            holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (WeatherHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        Weather weather = data[position];
        holder.txtTitle.setText(weather.title);
        holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(weather.icon);

        return row;
    }

    static class WeatherHolder
    {
        ImageView imgIcon;
        TextView txtTitle;
    }
}
```

in `getView() method` he creates object for `WeatherHolder` **what is this WeatherHolder class?**

1. How is it created?
2. Is it manually created by us?

> Because I cant find the body of the "WeatherHolder" class any where
>   else in the program.

I hope my question is clear. What is WeatherHolder in the program, who created that WatchHolder class.

Comment: The Wheatherholder class is a Class declared in Wheateradapter class, and it creates a wheatherholder if the row isn t created yet, if they are already created or != null he gets the wheaterholder from the current row

Comment: Thanks for the reply.... Can you elaborate me the use of WeatherHolder class

Comment: WheatherHolder is used to initialize your View on your layout, with this class you can access your views and could set field like setText() with the Array you have, to get the objects for the array there are a variable position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`during the scrolling of ListView` **findViewById()** `(which layout's children is inflated for a row of listview)` is called frequently, which can slow down performance. Even when the Adapter returns an inflated view for `recycling`, you still need to `look up the elements and update them`. A way around repeated use of findViewById() is to use the `view holder design pattern`.

A ViewHolder object stores each of the `component views inside the tag field of the Layout`, so you can `immediately access them without the need to look them up repeatedly`. First, you need to create a class to hold your exact set of views.

Here is the class in your code

```
static class WeatherHolder {
        ImageView imgIcon;
        TextView txtTitle;
}
```

> Yes it is manually created by us
>   in `getView()` u will create `Object` of that class and access it

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        WeatherHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new WeatherHolder();
            holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (WeatherHolder)row.getTag();
        }
//do ur staff
return row;
}
```

For more info [Visit here](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html)

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html