# How can i smooth listView scrolling?

Tags: android, android-listview

I am writing a media player application using Media extractor API. So my decoder decodes the data and shows content on surface. This is working fine. I have one list view. When i scroll this listview, it showing effect on decoder thread. So i am getting some disturbance. How can i resolve that. Is there any way to run my listView Adapter( getView() method) on separate thread? 
I saw this link. It may not helpful to me.
http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html Because My list item contain only one textView.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView txt_Effects;
        ImageView proImage;
        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_listview, null);
            txt_Effects= (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_row);
            proImage= (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.proImage_row);
        }
        else{
            txt_Effects= (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_row);
            proImage= (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.proImage_row);
        }

        txt_Effects.setText(data[position]);
        txt_Effects.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        proImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        if(position == previousSelectionIndex){
            txt_Effects.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);
            prevSelectedTextView= txt_Effects;
        }

        if(position>= startProIndex && position <= endProIndex){
            proImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }



        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: Please show your code. Especially the view adapter, where you create the views for the list.

Comment: are you using **ViewHolders** ?

Comment: @saa : why we use view holder pattern see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21848954/how-are-holders-in-custom-list-view-are-cerated/21849577#21849577 and `that link in ur question`  is helpful

Comment: @kaushik Thanks for your information. Let me change my adapter code. hten i ll let u know, if i have any problems with it.

Answer (score 2):

You should perform all "heavy" operations outside of getView() method. Consider using AsyncTask or ThreadPool for doing your "decoding" and then update your ListView in the UI thread.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use the **`ViewHolder`** pattern to improved the performance of loading your list items. Refer the following:

[Android ViewHolder Pattern Example](http://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html)

[Holder Pattern](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterperformance_hoder)

Hope it helps.