# ListView Rows can't be inflated

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am very new in Android and I'm trying to make a table for my application. I use listview  and a custom adapter to populate 9 data in a row. I thought that it should work, but the listview element is not shown when I run the application. Thank you for your help

Here is the part of my adapter class which I believe that have some problems:
**EDIT**

```
public class PlayerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
ArrayList<Player> PlayerList;
private Context mContext;

public PlayerAdapter(Context c,ArrayList<Player> List) {
    mContext = c;
    PlayerList=List;
}

public int getCount() {
        return PlayerList.size();
    }

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return PlayerList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return PlayerList.indexOf(getItem(position));
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if(convertView == null) {

             rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_activity, parent, false);
             viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
             viewHolder.text1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
             viewHolder.text2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
             viewHolder.text3 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
             viewHolder.text4 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
             viewHolder.text5 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
             viewHolder.text6 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView7);
             viewHolder.text7 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView8);
             viewHolder.text8 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView9);
             viewHolder.text9 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView10);
             rowView.setTag(viewHolder);        
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
             viewHolder.text1.setText(PlayerList.get(position)._name);
             viewHolder.text2.setText(""+PlayerList.get(position)._play);
             viewHolder.text3.setText(""+PlayerList.get(position)._win);
             viewHolder.text4.setText(""+PlayerList.get(position)._draw);
             viewHolder.text5.setText(""+PlayerList.get(position)._lose);
             viewHolder.text6.setText(""+PlayerList.get(position)._GD);
             viewHolder.text7.setText(""+PlayerList.get(position)._GF);
             viewHolder.text8.setText(""+PlayerList.get(position)._GA);
             viewHolder.text9.setText(""+PlayerList.get(position)._PTS);
            // set text for other TextViews too if u want to set value for each TextView I only show for 1st one
            return rowView;
        }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView text1;
        TextView text2;
        TextView text3;
        TextView text4;
        TextView text5;
        TextView text6;
        TextView text7;
        TextView text8;
        TextView text9;
    }
```

}

Here is my main program:

```
ArrayList<Player> PlayerList;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    PlayerList = new ArrayList<Player>();
    PlayerList.add(new Player("BER"));
    PlayerList.add(new Player("DOM"));
    PlayerList.add(new Player("FER"));
    PlayerList.add(new Player("HEN"));
    PlayerList.add(new Player("GAR"));
    PlayerList.add(new Player("JER"));
    PlayerList.add(new Player("JON"));
    PlayerList.add(new Player("IRV"));
    PlayerList.add(new Player("LIM"));

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.player_list);
    listView.setAdapter(new PlayerAdapter(this,PlayerList));
}
```

And, here is the Player Class:

**ADDED**

```
public class Player {
String _name;
int _play,_win,_draw,_lose,_GF,_GA,_GD,_PTS;

public Player(String name){
    _play=0;_win=0;_draw=0;_lose=0;_GF=0;_GA=0;_GD=0;_PTS=0;
    _name = name;
}

void play(int goal,int concede){
    _play++;_GF+=goal;_GA+=concede;_GD+=(goal-concede);
    if(goal>concede){
        _win++;
        _PTS+=3;
    }
    else if(goal<concede){
        _lose++;
    }
    else{
        _draw++;
        _PTS+=1;
    }

}
```

activity_main:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<TextView android:background="#000000" android:layout_margin="1dip" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_weight="0.3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:text="PLAYER" android:textColor="#fff"/>
<TextView android:background="#000000" android:layout_margin="1dip" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_weight="0.3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:text="P" android:textColor="#fff"/>
<TextView android:background="#000000" android:layout_margin="1dip" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_weight="0.3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:text="W" android:textColor="#fff"/>
<TextView android:background="#000000" android:layout_margin="1dip" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_weight="0.3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:text="L" android:textColor="#fff"/>
<TextView android:background="#000000" android:layout_margin="1dip" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_weight="0.3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:text="D" android:textColor="#fff"/>
<TextView android:background="#000000" android:layout_margin="1dip" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_weight="0.3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:text="GD" android:textColor="#fff"/>
<TextView android:background="#000000" android:layout_margin="1dip" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_weight="0.3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:text="GF" android:textColor="#fff"/>
<TextView android:background="#000000" android:layout_margin="1dip" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_weight="0.3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:text="GA" android:textColor="#fff"/>
<TextView android:background="#000000" android:layout_margin="1dip" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_weight="0.3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:text="PTS" android:textColor="#fff"/> 

</LinearLayout>
<ListView
android:id="@+id/player_list" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
```

Comment: please post the code where you set the adapter in your activity

Comment: show your code where you have set adapter in your class.

Comment: did you have all TextView id's in `list_view_activity`?

Comment: thanks for the responses,everyone. I have added the list_view_activity.xml and the main program.

Comment: @Lsancerio : u have `9 TextViews` for a `single row` of `ListView` or a `ListView` with `9 rows`

Comment: which one `9 TextViews` for a `single row`

Comment: oh sorry, both of them is the case. I accidentally have 9 rows with 9 TextViews inside each row. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Remove that for loop, get view method will take care of looping itself..

**EDIT**

You must initilize all the 10 textviews then only if you loop through will apply the text..

so initilize all 10 textviews outside the loop..

Comment: sorry for the incomplete description of my code. Let me describe here: In each row, I have 9 data, which are text views, to be displayed. That's why, I use a loop to set the text of these 9 text views on each list view. I also fed in the same data to all of them (playerArray[position]._name) instead of the actual code just for debugging purposes. Thank you in advance.

Comment: do you mean that I have to declare an array of textview outside the loop? I've actually done that before.. sorry If I mistakenly understood what you mean

Answer (score 0):

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_activity, parent, null);
         TextView textView;
        // **for(int i=0;i<9;i++){// Remove this for loop inside your code** 
             textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(tv[position]);
             textView.setText(playerArray[position]._name);
        // }
        return rowView;
    }
```

Comment: first change `tv[i]` to `tv[position]`, and we don't know details of `xml` or anything, with OP's code (if code is right) all `TextView` in row became one name that is `playerArray[position]._name`

Answer (score 0):

```
View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_activity, parent, false);
```

->

```
View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_activity, null);
```

Comment: hi, I have tried this, but I think it's not the problem here

Answer (score 0):

`getView()` is called for each `row` in the array you supplied to adapter. Hence you need to apply a loop in `getView()`.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_activity, parent, false);
         TextView textView;

             textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(tv[i]);
             textView.setText(playerArray[position]._name);

        return rowView;
    }
```

*Note: Also you need to make only `row-layout`, like in your case it seems you want to display every row with a single textview. Hence, your `R.layout.list_view_activity` should contain a textView only.
Say textView in `R.layout.list_view_activity` has id `description`. So following change would be needed.

```
textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById();
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't have to declare **`int[] tv`**

```
int[] tv = {R.id.textView2,R.id.textView3,R.id.textView4,R.id.textView5,R.id.textView6
                ,R.id.textView7,R.id.textView8,R.id.textView9,R.id.textView10};
```

and **`for loop`**

```
for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
             textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(tv[i]);
             textView.setText(playerArray[position]._name);
     }
```

**Changes u have to do**

**1.** In `getItemId(int position)` u returning `null` return the `position` like this

```
@Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }
```

**2.** In `getItem(int position)` u returning `null` return the `specific position of ur array` like this

```
@Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return playerArray[position];
    }
```

**3.** In `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` do something like this and try to follow **`ViewHolder`** pattern

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
ViewHolder viewHolder;
View rowView = convertView;
if(rowView == null) {
         LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_activity, parent, false);
         viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
         viewHolder.text1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
         viewHolder.text2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
         viewHolder.text3 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
         viewHolder.text4 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
         viewHolder.text5 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
         viewHolder.text6 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView7);
         viewHolder.text7 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView8);
         viewHolder.text8 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView9);
         viewHolder.text9 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView10);
         rowView.setTag(viewHolder);        
} else {
    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
}
         viewHolder.text1.setText(playerArray[position]);
        // set text for other TextViews too if u want to set value for each TextView I only show for 1st one
        return rowView;
    }

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView text1;
    TextView text2;
    TextView text3;
    TextView text4;
    TextView text5;
    TextView text6;
    TextView text7;
    TextView text8;
    TextView text9;
}
```

[Example of BaseAdapter to populate ListView using ArrayList(Ur Class)](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-baseadapter/)

[Why ViewHolder pattern see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21848954/how-are-holders-in-custom-list-view-are-cerated/21849577#21849577)

[Official tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html)

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

### SCREENSHOT :

[image]

### EDIT :

except `String` setText like this

```
viewHolder.text2.setText(String.valueOf(playerDataList.get(position)._play));
```

`list_view_activity` xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: hi, thank you very much for your response. It has been insightful. I tried your code and change some of the code in accordance with your reference (if you need, i could post my revised code). However, I still has an issue, that is the rowView is not displayed when I run the app. any idea? BTW, I just want to tell you that the playerArray is not an array of string. Instead, it is an array of Player (which is another class). Thanks, dude

Comment: check the size of `playerArray` *instead of* `Player[]` use `ArrayList<Player>`  and edit ur question with latest code

Comment: edited. Do i need to implement ArrayList instead of Array? Thank you

Comment: yes, that would be better and pass that in `listView.setAdapter(new PlayerAdapter(UrActivityName.this,ur_list<Player>));` and also change `Constructor` in `PlayerAdapter`

Comment: Hi, I have tried to change everything but it still doesn't work. Please take a look at the edited code

Comment: put ur `Player` class instead of `list_view_activity.xml`

Comment: welcome happy to help :) actually u forget about `getter` and `setter` method in `Player` class

Comment: I don't think that it's the reason. I know it's a bad practice but the     member here is not private, so it can be accessed outside the class. The problem is that the rowViews are not inflated at all in my application. Have you tried to run this code? :o

Comment: any screenshot? Mine is not showing the rows at all. I will upload the list_view_activity and the activity_main

Comment: if u want i will send u the project

Comment: wow.. anything wrong with my code? I could't upload my screenshot since I don't have enough reputation. Thanks, that would be very helpful. did you take a look at my activity_main.xml? Is there any problem?

Comment: okay. I think I found the problem.. When I removed the textviews element in the activity_main, the listview actually shows up. But I'm not sure why I can't include those textviews.

Comment: thank you very much for all of your help :) I know the error in the activity_main and it's now showing. Thanks :))