# Spinning wheel Progress Bar cloned in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I have a ListView populated with files as items. When I click on an item, an AsyncTask is launched, downloading the file.
Now while a file is being downloaded, I have a ProgressBar spinning next to its name in the ListView.

My problem is : when I click on certain items, the spinning wheel is also visible on other items in the listview even though I didn't click on them.

**CategoryActivity.java (Activity of the ListView, only the useful part) :**

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
int position, long id) {
// Récupère les valeurs depuis ListItem
udl = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.udl)).getText().toString();
loader = ((ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.spinWheel2));

filepath = dirpath + udl + ".pdf";
File file = new File(filepath);
if (file.exists()) { 
// If files exists I open it

}else{ // I download it
// There I set the ProgressBar to VISIBLE
loader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
// Call the AsyncTask
final DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask(CategoryActivity.this);
downloadTask.execute();                 
            }
        }
    });     
}
public static String getUdl(){
    return udl;
}
public static ProgressBar getLoader(){
    return loader;
}
```

**DownloadTask.java (only the useful part) :**

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {

    public static String url1 = some url;
    private static String url2 = "";
    private static String url3 = CategoryActivity.getUdl();
    public static ProgressBar loader = CategoryActivity.getLoader();
    private static String url = "";
    final static String dirpath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+ "/SomeDirectory/";
    public static String filepath = "";
    public static final String PREFS_TEXT = "PrefsTextView";

    private Context context;
    public DownloadTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        url3 = CategoryActivity.getUdl();
        loader = CategoryActivity.getLoader();
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        SharedPreferences codeSaveUrl = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_TEXT,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        url2 = codeSaveUrl.getString("defaut", ""); // Code Organisation
        url = url1 + url2 + "&file=" + url3 ;
        filepath = dirpath + url3 + ".pdf";

            //Download of the file
            HttpHandler hh = new HttpHandler();
            try {
                hh.download(url, filepath, this);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        return null;
    }

    public void doProgress(int value){ // Méthode appelée dans HttpHandler
         publishProgress(value);
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        StorageDirectory sd = new StorageDirectory();   // Appel à la classe StorageDirectory
        sd.callStorageDirectory();                      // Création du répertoire de stockage sur mémoire externe


    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
    }

    @Override // Evènement de post-execution
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // There I set the ProgressBar to GONE
        loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        if (result != null){
            Toast.makeText(context,"Erreur lors du téléchargement : "+result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
// Note that this message is correctly shown on screen when the download finishes
            Toast.makeText(context,"Le fichier a bien été téléchargé", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Every file is downloaded when I click on them, the only problem is the spinning wheel being cloned on other items.

**Edit : here are the images :**

When I click on this item :

[image]

The spinning wheel of this item (which is not on the screen at the same time as the first) shows too (its file is not downloaded though) :

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Do `ProgressBar` visible and invisible or gone in `Asynctask` not in `Activity`. If you use any Interface for `callBack` to activity from asyctask then do it in activity.

call `Asynctask` like this

```
// Don't set ProgressBar to VISIBLE here
//loader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
// Call the AsyncTask
final DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask(CategoryActivity.this, loader);
downloadTask.execute();
```

Change `DownloadTask's` constructer like this

```
public DownloadTask(Context context, ProgressBar pb) {
  this.context = context;
  this.pb = pb;//also declare pb globaly
  url3 = CategoryActivity.getUdl();
}
```

in `onPreExecute()` visible the `ProgressBar`

```
@Override 
protected void onPreExecute() {
   super.onPreExecute();
   pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   StorageDirectory sd = new StorageDirectory();// Appel à la classe StorageDirectory
   sd.callStorageDirectory();// Création du répertoire de stockage sur mémoire externe
}
```

in `onPostExecute(String result)` change the visibility of `ProgressBar` like this

```
pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);//instead of loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

**EDIT:**

Try to use [ViewHolder Pattern](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) for adapter also you can take a look at [this also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21848954/how-are-holders-in-custom-list-view-are-cerated/21849577#21849577)

Comment: The ProgressBar is still cloned on another item, and some don't even disappear anymore.

Comment: make sure in `xml` u have **setvisibility** to gone

Comment: The problem does not occur on a tablet, so I think it is due to the second item being out of the screen.

Comment: but the code is in `onItemClick` when `onItemClick` is fired the the code will execute.

Comment: Even with the code in `onItemClick`, if there are items out of the screen their spinner will appear

Comment: if it is `Spinner` not `LitView` use `onItemSelected`

Comment: Sorry as "spinner" I meant the ProgressBar, which is a spinning wheel.

Comment: Already did it. The code is perfectly executed. Like I said, it must be a displaying problem since it occures when there are items out of the screen. With a larger screen, if the entire ListView is visible, there is no problem.